# How to access Cognito Sync data of user accessing a Lambda through Proxy integration?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I'm providing an APIGateway Lambda Proxy function that gets called through the AWS SDK by a user who's authorized through AWS Cognito.

The function is supplied request details of the user, like the following parts:

```
headers:
   x-amz-security-token: 'xxxxxxx'

cognitoIdentityPoolId: 'x:xxxxxx-xxxxx',
accountId: '12345',
cognitoIdentityId: 'x:xxxxx-xxxx',
caller: 'XXXXXXX:CognitoIdentityCredentials',
apiKey: null,
sourceIp: '127.0.0.1',
accessKey: 'XXXXXX',
```

How can I use this data to access the users Cognito Sync data?

Answer (score 0):

Cognito opened up access to the sync store to developer credentials. You could reasonably use your own credentials inside Lambda to access the sync data for the identity id you have in the metadata.

Alternatively, if it's an unauthenticated id, you could just call getCredentialsForIdentity with that identity id and use those.